# Is it possible to reformulate the following objective function into a known form for optimization?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

We have the objective function to be minimized as

$$f_0(\textbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\textbf{a}_i^T \textbf{x}}{\textbf{x}^T 
 \textbf{B}_i \textbf{x}}$$

where $\textbf{x}, \textbf{a}_i$ are same sized vectors and $\textbf{B}_i$ is positive semidefinite matrix. My The values in $\textbf{a}_i$ are all positive and $\textbf{x}$ takes positive values as well.

The constraint on $\textbf{x}$ is linear. I just dont know how to simplify the objective function so I can use some sort of algorithm or optimization method to optimize the equation.

Comment: I suppose you mean to divide by $x^\top B_I x$.
It is not exactly clear why you think that function is convex, could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry I think I made a mistake. Its not convex but decreasing.

Comment: How large is the problem? I don't think there is any clever reformulation, so why not just use a standard general-purpose nonlinear solver?

Comment: I believe that in general your problem does not have a minimum. Look at the case of $N=1$. A function of type $f(x) = \frac{\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{x}}{\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{B} \mathbf{x}}$ for a positive $\mathbf{a}$ and a positive-definite $\mathbf{B}$ will have a positive value everywhere, and its value will approach zero as $||\mathbf{x}||$ approaches infinity. Thus, there is no global minimum point, since for any point you can find another point with a smaller value.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I dont have a lot of experience with cvx for instance. Do you think I can solve the optimization problem with some linear constraints just using cvx?

Comment: No, it is nonconvex so cvx is completely out of the picture. I've added an answer with an implementation with YALMIP

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Thanks a lot. Also can you explain how can you know if this function is convex or non convex?

Comment: Simply plot some, and you will see that it can become nonconvex

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I still cannot see how this is not convex after trying. If the matrix $\textbf{B}$ is positive semidefinite and all the elements of vector $\textbf{a}$ are positive, I think it is convex no?

Comment: Take for instance $(x+y)/(x^2+y^2)$. It is definitely not convex as you see when you plot it, or compute the Hessian.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow up on my comment that the problem is nonconvex and most likely does not have any clever reformulation, here is an implementation using the MATLAB Toolbox YALMIP (disclaimer, developed by me) to solve the nonlinear problem using either a local solver or a global solver.

```
% Create a random problem
n = 2;
a1 = rand(n,1);
a2 = rand(n,1);
B1 = randn(n);B1 = B1*B1';
B2 = randn(n);B2 = B2*B2';

% Create YALMIP model with some linear constraints
x = sdpvar(2,1)
Model = [.1 <= x <= 3];
Objective = (a1'*x/(x'*B1*x))+(a2'*x/(x'*B2*x));

% Try to solve using a local nonlinear solver
% YALMIP can get confused by this model  and this it is a geometric
% programming problem so we have to tell YALMIP to use non-gp formulation
% by using 'standard' flag
ops = sdpsettings('solver','fmincon-standard');
optimize(Model,Objective,ops);

% Use YALMIPs global solver and aim for global solution
ops = sdpsettings('solver','bmibnb','bmibnb.upper','fmincon');
optimize(Model,Objective,ops)

% Improve linear relaxations in global solver by adding redundant cuts
% which says the quadratics are non-negative, reducing likelihood of 
% singularities in relaxations
optimize([Model,cut([x'*B1*x x'*B2*x]>=0)],Objective,ops)
```

For efficiency, you should have an efficient LP solver installed (Gurobi, Mosek, SCIP, CPLEX, ...)

I found a bug when testing this problem, so you have to download the develop version of YALMIP on github if you want to run it.